# Will a VPN hide torrent activity from a network admin?

Tags: vpn, bittorrent, utorrent

I'm on a college campus, will a VPN be able to hide torrenting activity from a network admin? Just wondering really how VPN works.

Comment: Just a note: we're all assuming you're VPNing to a network that's not controlled by the college. If you're VPNing into a network the college set up, this won't help. :-)

Comment: Haha yeah its not a vpn setup by the college :P

Answer (score 2):

A VPN will encrypt your traffic, but if you are trying to use a torrent to download something to your current location, network admins might still see a large amount of outbound data compared to other computers.

Comment: K, so they will be able to see alot of ingoing/outgoing traffic.. but its all encrypted so they won't be able to tell whats in the packets correct?

Comment: Right -- there's no hiding the volume of traffic, but the contents should be hidden.

Comment: Kk cool, yeah im using wireshark now to see what the admins see.. interesting :p

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a VPN should "hide" your vpned traffic, as it's basically encapsulated and secured and passed along to the VPN host. It also allows you to avoid your ISP's [traffic shaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping).

There is a much more detailed explanation on [VPNs from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).

You may also want to look at [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)).

Comment: Thanks :) I wouldn't use Tor for that though. (cause they ask ppl not to)